# Attempting to nest if/else statement in while loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I'm setting up the following while loop to continue to print a message for each even number entered but print a different message for an odd number and stop:

```
userEnteredNumber = prompt("Please enter a number:");

while (userEnteredNumber%2 === 0) {
  if (userEnteredNumber%2 === 0) {
    document.write(userEnteredNumber + EVEN_MESSAGE);
  } else if (userEnteredNumber%2 !== 0) {
    document.write(userEnteredNumber + NOT_EVEN_MESSAGE);
  }
  userEnteredNumber = prompt("Please enter a number:");
  console.log(userEnteredNumber);
}
```

Right now it will continue to print with even number entry and stop if an odd number is entered, but the odd number message won't print. Not really understanding why the odd message won't print. Hoping someone can help clarify it for me!

Comment: because you have while(userEnteredNumber%2 === 0) so it will skip the whole while loop altogether

Comment: Is what I'm looking to do possible? IE, run the while loop with an even number, else print odd number message?  If so, what would that look like?

Comment: I guess you have to ask yourself, what are you actually trying to do? Why don't you just run the while loop without any odd/even condition (for example you can exit the loop if the number is less than 0), and then print the odd or even number based on the input?

Comment: This is part of a JS class where we are learning about while and for loops.  The prompt was "Write a program that asks a user to enter even numbers. As long as they enter an even number, display the number with a phrase that says, “ is an even number”. When the user enters a odd number, output the number with the phrase, “ isn’t an even number” and end the program."  I thought it might be possible to nest an if/else into the while loop.

Comment: ok.. to end the while loop, you can use break; ex snippet: while(true){if(even){write even}elseif(odd){write odd; break;}

Comment: break, got it!  Appreciate it, still learning available options for JS.  Thank you!

Comment: no worries.. learning is good, but don't forget to have fun.. :)

Answer (score 0):

More like this:

```
while (true) {

    userEnteredNumber = prompt("Please enter a number:");

    if (userEnteredNumber == null) { // they clicked cancel
       break;
    }

    if (userEnteredNumber%2 === 0) {
        document.write(userEnteredNumber + EVEN_MESSAGE);
    } else if (userEnteredNumber%2 !== 0) {
        document.write(userEnteredNumber + NOT_EVEN_MESSAGE);
    } else {
       document.write(NOT_VALID_MESSAGE + userEnteredNumber); 
    }

    console.log(userEnteredNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you can change it a bit to look like this:

```
while (true) {
  userEnteredNumber = prompt("Please enter a number:");
  if (userEnteredNumber%2 === 0) {
    document.write(userEnteredNumber + EVEN_MESSAGE);
  } else if (userEnteredNumber%2 !== 0) {
    document.write(userEnteredNumber + NOT_EVEN_MESSAGE);
    break;
  }
  console.log(userEnteredNumber);
}
```